# Getting canonicalize elem error on Rococo fork

Tags: rococo, astar

We are getting the error message below on Astar's custom relay chain, forked from Rococo, runtime is `rococo/9310`.

```
Could not canonicalize elem at pos 1549631 using key [12, 109, 109, 114, 63, 165, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 247, 105, 100, 142, 39, 51, 33, 71, 48, 77, 110, 205, 182, 188, 94, 219, 238, 166, 214, 115, 171, 201, 235, 230, 151, 64, 223, 58, 141, 185, 115, 10]
```

The error happens at every block imported, on both archive and full nodes.
Enabling off-chain indexing didn't solve the problem, neither upgrading client.

It doesn't prevent the nodes from running fine. Would anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please provide the source code of your node explicitly. If connecting with rococo using a forked relay node is likely to cause issues. What network are you trying?

Comment: The nodes are simply using Polkadot client from which we change chain specs, the client code is not forked.
Chain specs are available here: https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/master/bin/collator/res/tokyo.json

We deployed a bunch of test relay with this method previously, never encountered this error before.

Comment: This is an issue for Substrate, not a question. Please do not hesitate to click the button here https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/new/choose

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug in Substrate that is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the topic as it is an issue, issue opened here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13048